# Mobile ListView scroll and softkeyboard

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm developing an app with Apache Cordova and Kendo UI core. My app has a chat screen with an input field at the bottom with a send button, very similar to the common chat apps in the market.

My problem is when I tap on the send button and the soft keyboard hides. I want that it remains visible. I tried to set the focus to the input field on the onclick event of the send button but it doesn't work always.

My code:

```
function sendMessage(){
    var body = $("#chat-input").val();
    xmppConn.send($msg({
        to: jid,
        "type": "chat"
    }).c('body').t(body));
    messagesDS.add({message:body,
                        owner : true });
    scrollToBottom();
    $("#chat-input").focus();
}
```